# Getssl connection error

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt

I use getssl to install a Lets Encrypt SSL certificate. Below is the output of `./getssl -a`:

```
Check all certificates
hostname.com: Certificate on remote domain does not match, ignoring remote certificate
Registering account
Verify each domain
Verifying hostname.com
copying challenge token to /var/www/html/.well-known/acme-challenge/iWNVnBM81u5xITptieCF7J7sh70GhsDeSOLwAdY0bN0
Pending
getssl: hostname.com:Verify error:Could not connect to hostname.com
```

Of course hostname.com is my own name. I can reach the URL from external networks:

http://hostname.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/iWNVnBM81u5xITptieCF7J7sh70GhsDeSOLwAdY0bN0

This returns the right value. Below the ACL line in my getssl.cfg:

```
ACL=('/var/www/html/.well-known/acme-challenge')
```

Why does getssl give me a connection error? I run the same tool on other servers where this works fine.